# Create multiple users in mysql using a CSV file with specific privileges

Tags: mysql, csv

Create multiple users in mysql using a CSV file with specific privileges. 
Right now this is the code I have to create individual users

```
CREATE USER ikhan@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ikhan@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, FILE, CREATE, ALTER ON *.* TO ikhan@localhost;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to draw names from a csv and automate the creation of multiple accounts instead of creating them individually.

Comment: One option is to load the CSV into a table and then use a stored procedure ([13.1.12 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)), cursor ([13.6.6 Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)) and prepared statements ([13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)) to create users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways. Sticking to mysql only (since you have not indicated any programming language in the OP) and assuming that the csv contains username, host, password, and access rights, create a stored procedure that contains the following steps:

1. Create a temporary table that that has exactly the same fields as your csv file.
2. Import the csv file into the above created table using [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).
3. Open a cursor on the temporary table by selecting all rows and columns.
4. Using dynamic sql queries via [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), create users and grant access rights by executing the create user and grant commands.